# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: JNI (Internal Error)

Tags: vb.net, jvm, java-native-interface, c++-cli

I am trying to call VB DLL method in Java. I have succeeded in calling simple Hello World method.
Now I try to call a method that takes String as input and returns String as output.
The Wrapper DLL is compiled successfully. But on running the Java code, the error

**A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:**

**Internal Error (0xe0434352), pid=3668, tid=1124**

On searching, I found that following error comes mostly due to error in native code, which I can't figure out.

### Following is the log file:

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

Internal Error (0xe0434352), pid=1940, tid=2640

JRE version: 6.0_32-b05
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.7-b02 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
 Problematic frame:
 C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0x969b]

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

```
Current thread (0x002d9800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native,id=2640,            
stack(0x01940000,0x01990000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xe0434352, ExceptionInformation=0x80070002 0x00000000  
0x00000000 0x00000000 0x617c0000 

Registers:
EAX=0x0198ea44, EBX=0x00000005, ECX=0x00000005, EDX=0x00000000
ESP=0x0198ea44, EBP=0x0198ea94, ESI=0x0198eb04, EDI=0x00000001
EIP=0x75a3969b, EFLAGS=0x00000216

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0198ea44)
0x0198ea44:   e0434352 00000001 00000000 75a3969b
0x0198ea54:   00000005 80070002 00000000 00000000
0x0198ea64:   00000000 617c0000 00000001 00000000
0x0198ea74:   776a1e37 00000000 03ea11bc 00004000
0x0198ea84:   0022ae68 0198ea9c 001d9a98 0198ea4c
0x0198ea94:   0198eb38 618e48c7 e0434352 00000001
0x0198eaa4:   00000005 0198eb04 4dc4fa37 040ba034
0x0198eab4:   00227be0 0198ebf0 001d9a98 00000001 

Instructions: (pc=0x75a3969b)
0x75a3967b:   89 45 c0 c1 e0 02 50 ff 75 14 8d 45 c4 50 e8 9d
0x75a3968b:   d1 ff ff 83 c4 0c 8d 45 b0 50 ff 15 5c 11 a3 75
0x75a3969b:   c9 c2 10 00 89 45 c0 eb ed 90 90 90 90 90 8b ff
0x75a396ab:   55 8b ec 83 ec 1c 6a 00 6a 1c 8d 45 e4 50 6a 00 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x0198ea44 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x002d9800
EBX=0x00000005 is an unknown value
ECX=0x00000005 is an unknown value
EDX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
ESP=0x0198ea44 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x002d9800
EBP=0x0198ea94 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x002d9800
ESI=0x0198eb04 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x002d9800
EDI=0x00000001 is an unknown value

Stack: [0x01940000,0x01990000],  sp=0x0198ea44,  free space=314k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0x969b]  RaiseException+0x54
C  [clr.dll+0x1248c7]  DllGetClassObjectInternal+0x5f84e
C  [clr.dll+0x223abf]  GetHistoryFileDirectory+0x1427a
C  [clr.dll+0x22c222]  GetHistoryFileDirectory+0x1c9dd
C  [clrjit.dll+0x10cf]
C  [clrjit.dll+0x1f0b0]
C  [clrjit.dll+0x1a60]
C  [clrjit.dll+0x1c42]
C  [clrjit.dll+0x244d]
C  [clrjit.dll+0x401c]
C  [clrjit.dll+0x4132]
C  [clrjit.dll+0x4282]
C  [clrjit.dll+0x4595]
C  [clr.dll+0x33669]  CreateAssemblyNameObject+0x61d0
C  [clr.dll+0x33701]  CreateAssemblyNameObject+0x6268
C  [clr.dll+0x33743]  CreateAssemblyNameObject+0x62aa
C  [clr.dll+0x3399c]  CreateAssemblyNameObject+0x6503
C  [clr.dll+0x33496]  CreateAssemblyNameObject+0x5ffd
C  [clr.dll+0x340db]  CreateAssemblyNameObject+0x6c42
C  [clr.dll+0x1bcd5]  DllRegisterServerInternal+0x98c9
C  [clr.dll+0x2ae9]
C  0x03f0ba9e
j  CsharpConsumer.displayWithParam(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;+0
j  CsharpConsumer.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+50
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0xfad4b]
V  [jvm.dll+0x18c421]
V  [jvm.dll+0xfadcd]
V  [jvm.dll+0x95836]
V  [jvm.dll+0x9d778]
V  [jvm.dll+0xaf22b]
C  [java.exe+0x2155]
C  [java.exe+0x85b4]
C  [kernel32.dll+0x51154]  BaseThreadInitThunk+0x12
C  [ntdll.dll+0x5b299]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x63
C  [ntdll.dll+0x5b26c]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x36

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  CsharpConsumer.displayWithParam(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;+0
j  CsharpConsumer.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+50
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x01a24400 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3172,
    stack(0x03e00000,0x03e50000)]
  0x01a1e800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2236,
 stack(0x03db0000,0x03e00000)]
  0x01a1dc00 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5308, 
stack(0x03d60000,0x03db0000)]
  0x01a1b400 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3916, 
stack(0x03d10000,0x03d60000)]
  0x01a0c000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3660, 
stack(0x03cc0000,0x03d10000)]
  0x01a0a000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5116, 
stack(0x03c70000,0x03cc0000)]
=>0x002d9800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=2640, 
stack(0x01940000,0x01990000)]

Other Threads:
  0x019ce000 VMThread [stack: 0x03c20000,0x03c70000] [id=240]
  0x01a35c00 WatcherThread [stack: 0x03e50000,0x03ea0000] [id=2652]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 281K [0x23700000, 0x23c50000, 0x28c50000)
  eden space 4416K,   6% used [0x23700000, 0x23746498, 0x23b50000)
  from space 512K,   0% used [0x23b50000, 0x23b50000, 0x23bd0000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x23bd0000, 0x23bd0000, 0x23c50000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 0K [0x28c50000, 0x29700000, 0x33700000)
   the space 10944K,   0% used [0x28c50000, 0x28c50000, 0x28c50200, 0x29700000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 31K [0x33700000, 0x34300000, 0x37700000)
   the space 12288K,   0% used [0x33700000, 0x33707fb0, 0x33708000, 0x34300000)
    ro space 10240K,  54% used [0x37700000, 0x37c7ee18, 0x37c7f000, 0x38100000)
    rw space 12288K,  55% used [0x38100000, 0x387a27d8, 0x387a2800, 0x38d00000)

 Code Cache  [0x01a90000, 0x01b00000, 0x03a90000)
 total_blobs=116 nmethods=2 adapters=59 free_code_cache=33110656 largest_free_block=0
```

The VB code has a function that takes as input as string and outputs a string

```
Public Class Level2Display
    Public Function displayWithParam(str As String) As String
        Return "hello world" + str
    End Function
End Class
```

Here's the C++/CLI Wrapper code

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_CsharpConsumer_displayWithParam
(JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj, jstring myStr)
{

         const jchar* temp = (env)->GetStringChars(myStr, null); //Tried changing to JNI_FALSE, still the error persisted. 
        if(temp==NULL)
        {
             return NULL;
        }

        System::String^ managedString = gcnew System::String((const wchar_t*)temp);
        env->ReleaseStringChars(myStr, temp);

        Level2Display^ lds = gcnew Level2Display();    //class in the VB dll
        System::String^ result = (System::String^)lds->displayWithParam(managedString);         //displayWithParam method
        return env->NewStringUTF((const char*)System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(result).ToPointer());



}
```

Kindly help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is all screwed up.

```
return env->NewStringUTF((const char*)System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(result).ToPointer());
```

You've got a mismash of Ansi and UTF-8 and a memory leak.  I recommend never using any of the `Marshal` methods with `HGlobal` in the name.  (They violate the Single Responsibility Principle by doing both memory allocation and character set conversion, and they crash if you actually use them with real `HGLOBAL`s)

Instead, try

```
pin_ptr<const wchar_t> resultChars = PtrToStringChars(result);
return env->NewString(resultChars, result->Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using GetStringUTFChars instead of GetStringChars.  Does System::String make a deep copy of temp?  If not, call ReleaseStringChars after NewStringUTF or check the isCopy pointer.  Other than that, everything looks ok in the code you posted.

Comment: Java and .NET both use 16-bit chars, why would UTF8 be needed?

Comment: Not only that but GetStringUTFChars and NewStringUTF are for _modified_ UTF-8. And, `isCopy` is irrelevant to calling the release function.