# How to call a function with arguments in C++ from JAVA using JNI?

Tags: java, c#, c++, java-native-interface

I am messing around with this task for a while...

I am trying to call C# DLL methods from java.

I used [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/378826/How-to-wrap-a-Csharp-library-for-use-in-Java) as a tutorial, and it suggests building an intermediate c++ dll. But it uses a method without an argument, and I am affraid that it needs a modification for using a method with an argument. This is becuase I get an unsatisfiedlinkerror exception when I call t.SetCounter0("aaa") function in java.

This is the java code:

```
package jniTester;

import java.io.Console;

public class Test1 {

static {
    //System.load("c:\\Users\\ttene\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\CPM\\CPMPerformanceCountersController\\x64\\Debug\\CppWrapperDll.dll");
    System.load("c:\\Users\\ttene\\Documents\\Cpm2Java\\CppWrapperDll.dll");
}

public native void SetCounter0(String x);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Test1 t = new Test1();
        System.out.println("1");
        t.SetCounter0("aaa");
        System.out.println("2");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

This is the cpp:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "Java\jnicall.h"
#include "MCPP\CppWrapperDll.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Test1_SetCounter0  (JNIEnv *jn, jobject jobj) {

    std::cout << "Java_Test1_SetCounter0";

    // Instantiate the MC++ class.
    CppWrapperDllC* t = new CppWrapperDllC();

    // The actual call is made. 
    t->callCountersControl();
}
```

This is the h file:

```
#using <mscorlib.dll>
#using "CountersControl.netmodule"

using namespace System;

public __gc class CppWrapperDllC
{
    public:
        // Provide .NET interop and garbage collecting to the pointer.
        CountersControl __gc *t;

        CppWrapperDllC() {

            t = new CountersControl();
            // Assign the reference a new instance of the object
        }

    // This inline function is called from the C++ Code
    void callCountersControl() {

        t->SetCounter0("aaa");
    }
};
```

And at last this is the jni h file:

```
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class Test1 */

#ifndef _Included_Test1
#define _Included_Test1
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     Test1
 * Method:    SetCounter0
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Test1_SetCounter0(JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

I'll appreciate you assistance. Thanks.

Comment: >Try compiling the project Wink | ;) It doesn't work? Of course, who knows where jni.h is? By the way, you should know that jni.h helps the Java-C# interoption alot, read more materials Wink | ;) Add the Include directories: Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Include Directories -> Add 2 folders "%your jdk%/include" and "%your jdk%/include/win32"

Comment: It seems to be better (Smile)  , there are some small errors while compiling the library but I think google will help you.
Build C++ project into HelloWorld.dll then copy HelloWorld.dll and CSharpHelloWorld.netmodule to D:\. Run Test1.class and see what's happing. ...taken from this tuorial.

Comment: My hint: Try another tutorial e.g. [this](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html) seems to be more exact/detailed.

Comment: Dear xerx593, I tried also the tutorial you suggested. I now do not attempt to call C# dll but only C++ dll. The results are the same:      Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Test1.SetCounter0([C)V
        at Test1.SetCounter0(Native Method)
        at Test1.main(Test1.java:17)     The jni signature was changed to  JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Test1_SetCounter0 (JNIEnv *, jobject, jcharArray) since I now send char array.      I wish I could have sent you the short code snippets so you can see them.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use javah to create JNI-headers. If you had used it, the declaration in the header would actually have looked like this:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Test1_SetCounter0(JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring);
```

where jstring is the string passed as argument to `SetCounter0(...)`.

Comment: Thank you Paul. I did what you offered, and it really added jstring to the signature. No I get: C:\Users\ttene\Documents\Cpm2Java>java Test1
1
Java_Test1_SetCounter0#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (0xe0434352), pid=3340, tid=5060
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_31-b13) (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.31-b07 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0x940d]...

Comment: By the way, I had to remove the package from the file bacuase I couldn't  execute javah with it. I tried: javah -verbose -jni -classpath . jniTester.Test1 but it returned: Error: Could not find class file for 'jniTester.Test1'. I don't understand why. So I removes the packaged and it worked.

Comment: for the packaging issue: i use ant, so i don't have any experience with using javah from the commandline. for the error this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244288/a-fatal-error-has-been-detected-by-the-java-runtime-environment-jni-internal-e

Comment: Well, as you can see, I do not use any Marshaling methods, so this article is not relevant. Paul, do you have any more ideas? Thanks.

Comment: well, the errorcode itself only tells that some problems with .NET occured. But i can't tell anything more specific without the log and complete error message. Have you recompiled the dll and javacode after changing the JNI-header. This issue might be due to some incorrect methodname. Just a guess though.